# recursive factorial function post and pre increment

Tags: c++, recursion

I have just realised weird situation in c++ recursive programming.

I wrote this function then it returns nothing.

```
int recursive(int m)
{
    int n;
    if(m == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    n = recursive(m--); // If we change m-- with m-1 it returns correct answer
    return n * m;
}
```

Then suddenly i remembered m-- affect m at next line so my m value not changed. However --m affect immediately at current line. I tried but returns 0.

Can you explain why these appears?
Thanks.

Comment: It returns zero because you are multiplying `n*m`, where m will be zero in the final call.

Comment: Also, code formatting is for humans

Comment: You shouldn't use mutating operations in recursive functions. `m-1` would be correct and `m--` is better in loop iterations.

Comment: @NedStark sory for my wasting your time. Its dummy and stupid mistake. Sorry. You re right returns 0 because final step is 0.